# Faster way to associate two pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two pandas Dataframes:

> automate

```
index   id  user_id merchant_id marketing_email_id  start_date  end_date    email_status    created_at
0   133198  133199  10939   88  681 2016-06-29  2016-07-06  1   2016-06-29 11:26:46
1   578787  578788  226281  745 1636    2017-09-14  2017-09-21  0   2017-09-14 12:32:32
2   222373  222374  86557   37  1274    2016-12-31  2017-01-07  0   2016-12-31 13:31:18
3   279039  279040  92109   669 1470    2017-03-01  2017-03-15  0   2017-03-01 12:09:27
4   33913   33914   25422   155 652 2016-02-22  2016-02-27  1   2016-02-22 12:45:15
5   423084  423085  29820   509 2067    2017-06-19  2017-06-20  1   2017-06-19 10:00:43
6   592752  592753  368756  1310    2827    2017-09-21  2017-09-28  0   2017-09-21 06:03:49
7   660899  660900  13007   206 2189    2017-10-19  2017-10-26  0   2017-10-19 07:47:48
8   491336  491337  125266  745 1626    2017-07-26  2017-08-02  0   2017-07-26 11:31:28
9   424653  424654  115139  687 1832    2017-06-20  2017-06-27  0   2017-06-20 07:33:03
```

> visit

```
    user_id merchant_id visit_verified
created_at          
2015-02-09 10:57:05 57  29  1
2015-02-09 14:23:12 58  30  1
2015-02-09 14:29:14 58  30  1
2015-02-09 14:51:26 59  30  1
2015-02-09 16:14:50 60  29  1
2015-02-09 16:17:22 61  30  1
2015-02-09 17:44:20 62  30  1
2015-02-09 17:46:57 63  30  1
2015-02-09 17:53:26 60  29  1
2015-02-09 18:03:40 64  29  1
```

I'm trying to associate for each row in the automate table, if there is a corresponding row in the visit table, where the created_at is between the start_date and the end_date.

Following is the code used to calculate it:

```
automate.iloc[1,"visit"] = visits[visits.user_id.isin([automate.iloc[1].user_id])][automate.iloc[1].start_date:automate.iloc[1].end_date].index.values
```

The issue arises on replicating the above for all **700k rows** in the automate table. 
Iterating over each row in the automate table seems to be **very slow**. I've used the **df.iterrows** function, but I'm unable to assign values to each row.

Is there a faster method that I could use for the above said logic ?

EDIT 1 :
The expected output should be

```
index   id  user_id merchant_id marketing_email_id  start_date  end_date    email_status    created_at  Visit
0   133198  133199  10939   88  681 2016-06-29  2016-07-06  1   2016-06-29 11:26:46 NaN
1   578787  578788  226281  745 1636    2017-09-14  2017-09-21  0   2017-09-14 12:32:32 NaN
2   222373  222374  86557   37  1274    2016-12-31  2017-01-07  0   2016-12-31 13:31:18 NaN
3   279039  279040  92109   669 1470    2017-03-01  2017-03-15  0   2017-03-01 12:09:27 NaN
4   33913   33914   25422   155 652 2016-02-22  2016-02-27  1   2016-02-22 12:45:15 NaN
```

Here the NaN values may or may not be filled with a timestamp value(s), if a given user visited within the start-end date.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output ?

Comment: added the expected output. Please see

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, yeah thats a hard one. The only recommendation I have is maybe sorting both dataframes by the date/time, then ...well here is some pseudo code:

```
dfautomate2 = dfautomate.sortby(start_date)
dfvisit = dfvisit.sortby(created_at)
listofawesome = []
for visit in dfvisit:
    for event_range in dfautomate2:
        if event_range.start_date < visit.created_at < event_range.end_date:
            print("WINNING")
            listofawesome.append(event_range)
        else:
            dfautomate[event_range].delete #its been a while since I used pandas, but you get the idea
```

Definitely not the prettiest, and there probably is a faster/better way to do it.

The idea is, if both dataframes are sorted newest to oldest, and you run through the visits, if you are always on the earliest visit, you can delete the rows in the automation df that are before it...that way in the next for loop you won't have to check ones earlier than the last visit, because they were already gone through.

May not work for your situation, lemme know if you come up with a solution though, this is a good one.